# Function with bounded derivative as ODE

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, signal-processing, control-theory

Given a function $x(t)$, I am looking for a function $y(t)$ which closely follows $x(t)$ except that its derivative must be bounded by a constant $c$, i.e. $\dot{y} \leq c$. Is there a way to describe $y(t)$ as ODE?

EDIT: Is there a way to design a low pass filter for $x(t)$ such that the derivative of the resulting function is bounded by $c$ everywhere?

EDIT2: Since my question is not very well formulated, I asked a more precise question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823952/low-pass-filter-as-linear-ode-with-bounded-derivative).

I appreciate your hints.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "closely follows"?
Are you making any assumptions on $x(t)$, e.g. 
$x(t) = O(|t|)$ as $t \to \pm\infty$?

Comment: By "closely follows" I mean that $y(t)$ minimizes the distance to $x(t)$ subject to the constraint $\dot{y} \leq c$. In particular if $\dot{x} \leq c$ then $y(t) = x(t)$.

Comment: I don't have any specific assumptions wrt. $x(t)$. I should have said "follows as closely as possible" instead of "closely follows".

Comment: Do you want y to be $C^1$?  If so then you wouldn't have $x'<C \Rightarrow y(t)=x(t)$.  I guess you meant in the comment that $x'<C$ everywhere though.  It seems to me that there is no minimizer:  The minimum would have discontinuous derivative in nontrivial examples.

Comment: Yes, I want $y \in C^1$. Thus, $x \in C^1 \wedge \dot{x} \leq c \Rightarrow x(t) = y(t)$. With $\dot{x} \leq c$ I mean $\forall t \frac{dx}{dt} \leq c$, i.e. the derivative is bounded everywhere. In fact, I thought of a low pass filter design such that $\dot{y}$ meets the bound.

Comment: A specific interpretation of my question is answered [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16758/first-order-low-pass-filter-with-bounded-derivative).

Comment: @od3 Your question is an interesting one and potentially useful in some control problems. I think you might get some hints by looking at reference governors.